# Suppose $p$ is an odd prime. Show that $1^{p-1} +2^{p-1}+ \ldots +(p-1)^{p-1}\equiv -1\pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $p$ is an odd prime.  Show that $1^{p-1} +2^{p-1}+ \ldots +(p-1)^{p-1}\equiv -1\pmod p$. 
I think I need to use Wilson's Theorem on this but I'm not sure how. 
I believe I am suppose to factor it somehow too but also I'm lost at this point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use Fermat's Little Theorem on each term, and then count the terms.

Comment: So then would they all equal one?

Comment: Right, and then it's just $1$ added to itself $p-1$ times.